# react native - send update/data to previous screen via current screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

So my first screen, say `ParentScreen` has a `FlatList` of a component. When any component of the list is clicked, it opens another screen `ChildScreen`. Now what I'm trying to do is that when I perform an action on the `ChildScreen`, the `ParentScreen`'s FlatList needs to be updated.

I'm using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), so my current approach is to send props via passProps property via `this.props.navigator.push()` but when I perform an action on the ChildScreen, it's unable to update that data because the `ParentScreen` is frozen at that time, hence it gives me the error:

> You attempted to set the key `count` with the value `3` on an object
>   that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.

How can I communicate this data OR do a workaround to allow the same.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about react-redux, with that you can manage your states and pass data from one componet to the other by mapping states to props, you will learn about reducers, combine reducers and actions.

this youtube link can help you alot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucd5x3Ka3gw

Comment: I already use redux for some other things, but I'm not sure if redux is the right way to go ahead for this.

Comment: The youtube video is a series from 1 to 7, am sure you get others online, feel free to ask me questions here, but make sure you have tried out whatever you will learn from the videos

Comment: @KetanMalhotra, i am sure redux will work, i have used redux, to manage my state, once you have mapped your state to props, you can manipulate the data and use componentWillReceiveProps to listen to changes in props and with that you can set your state data.

Comment: Send a function from Parent screen and call it from child screen so any changes can be updated to Parent screen from Child screen